# How to change form action attribute value based on datalist selection

Tags: jquery

I've looked at countless examples on here and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to change the form action based on the selected value from a dropdown menu. Why won't this work?

Basically, the HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="storetable" autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
<label>STORE:</label>
  <input type="text" list="storeID" name="store" placeholder="Choose a store..." required>
       <datalist id="storeID">
          <option value="cwb_coins">Causeway Bay</option>
          <option value="wc_coins">Wan Chai</option>
          <option value="lck_coins">Lai Chi Kok</option>
          <option value="tp_coins">Tai Po</option>
       </datalist>
</form
```

javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#storeID").change(function(){
   var url =  $(this).children(":selected").text(); //get the selected option value
   switch (url) 
  {
   case "cwb_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','cwb_coin_code.php');
   //changing action attribute of form to cwb_coin_code.php
   break;
   case "wc_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','wc_coin_code.php');
   break;
   case "lck_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','lck_coin_code.php');
   break;
   case "tp_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','tp_coin_code.php');
   break;
   default:
       $("#storetable").attr('action', '#');
   }
   }); 
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the wrong value to the attribute - you need the actual value of the sleected option - not the text content

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#store").change(function(){
   var url =  $('#store').val(); //get the selected option value
   console.log('action: ' + url);
   switch (url) 
    {
     case "cwb_coins":
      $("#storetable").attr('action','cwb_coin_code.php');
       break;
     case "wc_coins":
       $("#storetable").attr('action','wc_coin_code.php');
        break;
     case "lck_coins":
        $("#storetable").attr('action','lck_coin_code.php');
         break;
     case "tp_coins":
        $("#storetable").attr('action','tp_coin_code.php');
        break;
     default:
       $("#storetable").attr('action', '#');
   }
   }); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="storetable" autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
<label>STORE:</label>
  <input type="text" id="store" list="storeID" name="store" placeholder="Choose a store..." required>
       <datalist id="storeID">
          <option value="cwb_coins">Causeway Bay</option>
          <option value="wc_coins">Wan Chai</option>
          <option value="lck_coins">Lai Chi Kok</option>
          <option value="tp_coins">Tai Po</option>
       </datalist>
</form>
```

EDIT - refactored to not even need values on the options - note that when you don't include a value - the value is the option text. This way you can use the selected option's text as the variable value in your switch statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#store").change(function(){
   var url =  $(this).val(); //get the selected option value

   switch (url) 
    {
     case "Causeway Bay":
      $("#storetable").attr('action','cwb_coin_code.php');
       break;
     case "Wan Chai":
       $("#storetable").attr('action','wc_coin_code.php');
        break;
     case "Lai Chi Kok":
        $("#storetable").attr('action','lck_coin_code.php');
         break;
     case "Tai Po":
        $("#storetable").attr('action','tp_coin_code.php');
        break;
     default:
       $("#storetable").attr('action', '#');
   } 
   console.log('action: ' + $('#storetable').attr('action'));
   }); 
   
     
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="storetable" autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
<label>STORE:</label>
  <input type="text" id="store" list="storeID" name="store" placeholder="Choose a store..." required>
       <datalist id="storeID">
          <option>Causeway Bay</option>
          <option>Wan Chai</option>
          <option>Lai Chi Kok</option>
          <option>Tai Po</option>
       </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: One suggestion - a datalist is useful if there are other possible options that the user could type in - if you  only wnat the 4 specific options to choose from then a select list is the better HTML element - if so - let me know and I will refactor my answer to the select list using the options you have listed. - also - get in the habit of console logging everything - then you can see what values are passed to where etc.

Comment: And also - if you don't want the value of the option to show in the data-list - then you can refactor the code to use a data-attribute - (... <option data-value="cwb_coins">Causeway Bay</option> ...) then use hte JS to pick up that data-value attribute value and apply it as the action...

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do that. I used the datalist because I did not want to restyle the select

Comment: @gavfgrif   how do pick up the data-value attribute in js?

Comment: @Chase -  Actually - was just going to include that - then i realised there is a simpler way - not use a value at all and just change the conditions in the switch statemtn to the actual text of the options - check out the second portion of my answer.

Comment: @gavfgrif Thank you! I just learned so much that I was struggling to piece together. I don't have my first javascript class till the coming semester so I'm trying to learn some.

Comment: @Chase - no probs - its good to try to learni as much as you can - one suggestion - try learning how to do things in plain ('vanllla' js) instead of jquery. There is a lot that you can do with the newer selectors (such as document.querySelector) that means you may not need jQuery. And its easier to convert to jQuery after you have learned the foundation of JS. And don't put too much pressure on yourself - there are lots of tutorials around on learning js. - just start off with the basics and build from that.